# Can I use Indy Sockets in Visual C++?

Tags: sockets, visual-c++, indy

I would like to port Borland(Embarcadero) C++ Builder 2010 project to Visual C++. The hurdle is Indy Sockets library. It works great, but I need it on Microsoft native stack (not managed C# port).

Simply pulling Indy includes into VC++ project ends up ugly with stuff like:

```
#if __BORLANDC__ < 0x500
#error BCW 5.0 or greater required
#endif
```

or
    #pragma delphiheader begin

and doesn't compile...

Is it even possible?

-Stan

Answer (score 1):

Indy is written in Delphi Pascal, and as such can only be compiled with a Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero or FreePascal compiler.

Indy 10 supports .NET, but its .NET assembly binaries have not been recompiled in a long time (you would have to use a Delphi.NET compiler to compile the latest code from Indy's SVN).  Indy 11 will likely drop support for .NET, though.

In order to use Indy in a Visual C++ environment, you will have to wrap it inside of a Delphi/FreePascal-written DLL first.